# Is there a way to send a mail seamlessly using Office.js?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've built my first outlook.web.addin using office.js,

But I need a way to send a predefined mail to a certain recipient without showing the user a 'message compose ' screen...

Below code opens compose screen, but I can't send without forcing the user to push the send button.

```
function sendMessage() {

    if (Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType === Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message) {
        var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
        var item = mailbox.item;
        var itemId = item.itemId;
        if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
            item.saveAsync(function(result) {
                itemId = result.value;
            });
        }

        Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm(
            {
                // Copy the To line from current item.
                toRecipients: ['xxx@xxx.net'],
                ccRecipients: ['yyy@yyyy.com'],
                subject: 'Outlook add-ins are cool!',
                htmlBody: 'Hello <b>World</b>!<br/><img src="cid:image.png"></i>',
                attachments: [
                    {
                        type: 'item',
                        name: 'Suspected phishing mail',
                        itemId: itemId
                    }
                ]
            });

    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

I need to modify the above code to be something like:

```
function sendMessage() {

    if (Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType === Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message) {
        var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
        var item = mailbox.item;
        var itemId = item.itemId;
        if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
            item.saveAsync(function(result) {
                itemId = result.value;
            });
        }

        var newItem = mailbox.item;
        newItem.to.setAsync(["xxx@xxx.net"]);
        newItem.body.setAsync(["This is a test message"]);
        newItem.addItemAttachmentAsync(
            itemId,
            "Welcome email"
            );
        newItem.saveAsync(
            function callback(result) {
                alert(result);
            });
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

I expect to send the message without allowing the user to change any details in the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish something like this by making a [CreateItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/createitem-operation-email-message) EWS request using [MakeEWSREquestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox#makeewsrequestasyncdata-callback-usercontext). The sample below will send an e-mail to yourself, but you can modify as you need.

```html
var request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
 '  <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /></soap:Header>'+
 '  <soap:Body>'+
 '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">'+
 '      <m:SavedItemFolderId><t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" /></m:SavedItemFolderId>'+
 '      <m:Items>'+
 '        <t:Message>'+
 '          <t:Subject>Hello, Outlook!</t:Subject>'+
 '          <t:Body BodyType="HTML">Hello World!</t:Body>'+
 '          <t:ToRecipients>'+
 '            <t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>' + Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress + '</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox>'+
 '          </t:ToRecipients>'+
 '        </t:Message>'+
 '      </m:Items>'+
 '    </m:CreateItem>'+
 '  </soap:Body>'+
 '</soap:Envelope>';

Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, function (asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
    showMessage("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
  }
  else {
    showMessage("Message sent!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked magically, but how can I send the current email as attachment ?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to look up details of EWS to see what is possible. You do have the current item itemId, from Office.JS.